# Components dont rerender when redux store is updated

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a connected top level component :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import store from './store/store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import LifePlanner from './lifePlanner';
import { getContainer, setContainer } from './store/plannerSlice'

class App extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("/lp/top-layer", { mode: 'cors' }).then((response) => {
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
          response.status);
        return;
      }
      response.json().then((data) => {
        store.dispatch(setContainer({ name: "Root Container", children: data.data.containers }));
        this.setState({ container: getContainer(store.getState()) })
      });
    }
    ).catch(function (err) {
      console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
    });
  }


  render() {
    let c = this.state.container;
    if (c.name) {
      return <LifePlanner container={c} />
    }
    return <h1>Loading</h1>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
  ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

`LifePLanner` then calls an `ExpandedCard` component, psasing the container down and then again to a `ImageCard` component where I put an onClick, which changes the `openContainer` item in the store

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActionArea from '@material-ui/core/CardActionArea';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import {  setContainer } from '../store/plannerSlice'
import store from '../store/store';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  media: { height: 250 },
});

export default function SectionCard({ id, name, image, description, children }) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const handleClick = () => {
    fetch(`/lp?${id}`, { mode: 'cors' }).then((response) => {
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
          response.status);
        return;
      }
      response.json().then((data) => {
        store.dispatch(setContainer({ name , children: data.data.containers }));
      });
    }
    ).catch(function (err) {
      console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
    });
  }
  return (
    <Card className={classes.root} onClick={()=>handleClick()}>
      <CardActionArea>
        {image &&
          <CardMedia
            className={classes.media}
            image={image}
            title="Contemplative Reptile"
          />}
        <CardContent>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
            {name}
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
            {description}
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>
      {(children && children.length > 0) &&
        <CardActions>
          <Button size="small" color="primary">
            Expand (Contains {children.length} items)
          </Button>
        </CardActions>
      }
    </Card>
  );
}
```

Heres my reducer too:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'containers',
  initialState: {
    openContainer: {}
  },  
  reducers: {
    setContainer: (state, action) => {
      let payload = action.payload;
      state.openContainer  = {...payload}
    },
  },
});

export const getContainer = state => {
  return state.containers.openContainer
};

export const { setContainer } = slice.actions;

export default slice.reducer;
```

None of the components get their componentWilLReceiveProps triggered or get notified of the change, but **the store does get the change from the click**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's several issues here.  The primary problems are:

- You're interacting with the store directly in our components.  Instead, you should be using [the React-Redux APIs like `connect` and `useSelector/useDispatch`](https://react-redux.js.org) to read data from the store and dispatch actions in your components.  That way they'll update properly when the store state gets updated.
- You shouldn't be copying data from props to state just to render with it.  [Copying data from props to state is almost always the wrong approach](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html).

A few other notes:

- Conceptually, [think of actions as "events that happened", not "setters"](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#model-actions-as-events-not-setters).  Instead of calling that reducer/action `setContainer`, call it something like `containerDataLoaded`.
- You don't need to spread `{...payload}` in that reducer, since the object was constructed when you dispatched the action.  You can simplify that line to `state.openContainer = action.payload`.
- You might want to consider using `async/await` syntax instead of promise chaining.